# Using Flask's MongoEngine. Error with datetime field

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime, flask-mongoengine

I have a model with the a datetime field

```
user_since = db.DateTimeField()
```

When I try to insert a new object of the model into mongo, There is no error. But the write does not succeed.

I printed the object from to_json() and tried to insert it with mongo shell, I get the following error.

```
field names cannot start with $ [$date] at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:L147
```

the to_json had this field.

```
"user_since": {"$date": 1392205572989}
```

I can't seem to find any pointers on how to solve this.

What is causing the write to fail?

How can I make mongoengine to throw error in case of write failure.? Or at least find out what the error was?

Thanks.

Update:
As I found later the real problem is not the datetime field. The details of the problem are in this question [MongoEngine Document Object made using from_json doesn't save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731860/mongoengine-document-object-made-using-from-json-doesnt-save)

Comment: Can you provide more context around the write? Also, can you disclose the entire model?

Comment: Please find the details in this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731860/mongoengine-document-object-made-using-from-json-doesnt-save

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB you cannot have '$' at the beginning of the field name.

[MongoDB Limits and Thresholds - Restrictions on Field Names](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions%20on%20Field%20Names):

> Field names cannot contain dots (i.e. .), dollar signs (i.e. $), or
>   null characters. See [Dollar Sign Operator Escaping](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-dollar-sign-escaping) for an alternate
>   approach.

Try to name it differently.

---

edit:
According to [MongoEngine documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.DateTimeField), you could pass db_name parameter:

> db_field – The database field to store this field in (defaults to the
>   name of the field)

Comment: I am not using pymongo. I am not naming the $date field myself. I just made models mongoengine defining a datetime field.

Is there any way to get the reason why write failed.?

Comment: Try: DateTimeField(db_field='date')